# tmux - output all keybindings to a file

Tags: bash, zsh, tmux

I have checked [Write all tmux scrollback to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442424/206574) and came up with the following command to view scrollback buffer is vscode.

```
bind-key -T root C-E run-shell "tmux capture-pane -pS -50000 > /tmp/tmux-code.txt; code /tmp/tmux-code.txt"
```

Now I want to view `<prefix>`<kbd>?</kbd> (List all key bindings) output in vscode.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP Here.

The answer seems to be `tmux list-keys > keybindings.txt`